# Php code to extract xml file data to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have XML file.. I need to convert it form XMl to MYSQL. . now my question how to extract this two array

Each array will have different

```
    <r> $value </r>
```

$value of data..for example for 

first array, 

pmIntervalTxEthMaxUtilization data : 34,2 and

for second array 

pmIntervalRxPowerLevel data: -9,70 , 

pmIntervalTxPowerLevel data: 13,1

. can some one help to guide how write php code to extract this xml file to MY SQL

```
    <mi>
        <mts>20130618020000</mts>
        <gp>900</gp>
        <mt>pmIntervalRxUndersizedFrames</mt>  [ this is 1st array]
            <mt>pmIntervalTxEthMaxUtilization</mt>
        <mv>
            <moid>port:1:3:23-24</moid>
            <sf>FALSE</sf>
            <r>0</r>    [the data for 1st array i want to insert in DB]
            <r>34</r>
        </mv>
                     <mv>
            <moid>port:1:3:23-24</moid>
            <sf>FALSE</sf>
            <r>0</r>    [the data for 1st array i want to insert in DB]
            <r>2</r>
        </mv>
    </mi>
    <mi>
        <mts>20130618020000</mts>            
        <gp>900</gp>
         <mt>pmIntervalRxSES</mt>            [this is 2nd array]
        <mt>pmIntervalRxPowerLevel</mt>
        <mt>pmIntervalTxPowerLevel</mt>
        <mv>
            <moid>client:1:3:23-24</moid>
            <sf>FALSE</sf>
            <r>0</r>   [the data for 2nd array i want to insert in DB]
            <r>-9</r>
            <r>13</r>
        </mv>
                     <mv>
            <moid>client:1:3:23-24</moid>
            <sf>FALSE</sf>
            <r>0</r>   [the data for 2nd array i want to insert in DB]
            <r>70</r>
            <r>1</r>
        </mv>
    </mi>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Debugging request of larger chunks of non-isolated code that may (or may not) contain the code the question asks about. Instead the code should be reduced the a bare minimum example code that outlines the problem and question in a compact and self-explaining manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isnt very clear to me, do you mean something like a nested loop:

```
foreach($xml->mi as $mi){
    // This deep we loop through each <mi> value
    foreach($mi->mv as $subchild){
    // Now we loop through each <mv> of the <mi> from the outer loop
    // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. but different loop ( i have two different loop here) will have different data..

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested loop:

```
foreach($xml->mi as $mi)
{
    foreach($mi->mv as $subchild)
    {
        ...
        insert row
        ...
    }
}
```

This will loop over each `<mi>` node, and subsequently for each `<mv>` that it contains.

Comment: ok..tq for helping 
but different loop ( i have two different loop here) will have different data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code when we have two array with different content of data

```
$i = 0 ;
foreach($xml->md->mi as $mi)    
        { 
            foreach($mi->mv as $subchild)
            {   
                if ($i <2 )
                { 
                  //function code for 1st array
                    $i++;
                }   

                else
                {
                     //function code for 2nd array
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
```